# Calling a HTTPS REST Endpoint throws "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

Tags: .net, rest, ssl, tls1.2

First of all, I have not that much knowledge of SSL.

On a server an app is running that provides a REST interface which supports TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.1. The secure connection is additionally secured by a required client certificate.

I installed the *.cer file (that I got from the producer of the server app) in my local machines certificate store (Personal and Trusted Root Authorities).

Now when I try to connect to the API using the *.pfx file and the password (also got from the producer of the server app) as follows:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add( new X509Certificate2( "C:\\_Work\\client.pfx", "test" ) );    
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;

using( HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient( handler ) )
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri( "https://server:8093" );

    string plainHeaderValue = "foo:bar";
    string encodedHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( plainHeaderValue ) );
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue( "Basic", encodedHeaderValue );

    string resource = "/foo/bar";
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync( resource ).Result;
}
```

I am getting the exception "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream." at the GetAsync() call:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The API works with HTTP. The Port 8093 is the correct HTTPS port for the app. The passwords and files should be correct as well.

I am using .NET Framework 4.8.

Any idea here? I have no clue :/

Thank you!

Comment: In my experience the most productive way to troubleshoot issues like this is to run Wireshark on the server side and inspect the logs - failed protocol handshakes will be highlighted in red (IIRC), and the message has info on why it failed.

Comment: Side notes: do not set `SecurityProtocol` manually, allow the system to decide the best TLS version. `handler` and `response` need `using` . Do not use `.Result`, only use `await` otherwise you could deadlock.

Comment: Its only rudimentary here

Comment: Okay fixed it. The *.cer file had to be imported on the server as well.